# Figures for this patent?

Tags: wo2012125157a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2012125157A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2012125157A1)

Where can I find the Figures for this patent.  Google search only shows the text?
Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 1):

Check the associated US patent application, [US20130346950](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130346950).

---

By reviewing the details section on Ask Patents, you can find the "Also published as" listings for this application.

[image: screenshot from Google Patents]

There, you can see that this was also filed in the United States, as application number [US20130346950](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130346950). By clicking that link, you can find the five images associated with it.

Comment: though family patents are same but in some cases there can be changes in national phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the methods:-

Via  WIPO:-

1. Check drawing section [Link](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/WO2012125157)
2. Download the pdf version, from documents tab

Via EPO

1. Check mosaic section of [Link](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?FT=D&date=20120920&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&locale=en_EP&CC=WO&NR=2012125157A1&KC=A1&ND=5)

   2. download original document in pdf form